# why is my pdf not showing in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display a pdf file in an html template and also be able to update that pdf file, I read the tutorials on how to display a pdf file but I'm not sure why mine isn't really working, I have a model called `Reference`

```
class References(models.Model):

    REFERENCE_MATERIAL = (
        ('seating', 'Seating Plan'),
        ('organization', 'Organization Chart')
    )

    # the variable associated with the reference
    reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REFERENCE_MATERIAL,)

    reference_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='references/')

    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)


    # on submit click of update entry page, it redirects to the url below.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('references-home')
```

Here are the views to update a reference and the one that displays it

```
class SeatingReferenceView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'seating_plan'
    template_name = 'catalog/references-seating.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return References.objects.filter(reference_name='seating').order_by('date_updated').first()

def reference_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadReference(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('references-home')
    else:
        form = UploadReference()
    return render(request, 'catalog/references_update.html', {'form': form,})
```

Here is my template

```
<div class="container maintenance-container">


  <div class="row" >
    <div class="maintenance-title">
      <h1 class="mainrow">Seating Plan</h1>
      <h4 class="maintenance-under">Seating Plan for Kitchener Floor 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      {% if seating_plan %}
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        {{ seating_plan.read }}
      </div>



      {% else %}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="mainpanelcontent">
             <h4>There are no seating plans to display</h4>
          </div>

        </div>

      {% endif %}

  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

However I'm receiving nothing in my html template, I am storing my files in a folder under `/media/references`, I can see the files are in there currently and I can see in my database that under the `reference_file` column that there are files called `seatingplan.pdf` but still nothing is showing. Thank you !

Comment: You haven't shown the template where you display the PDF, nor have you described how you are serving uploaded files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My apologies, i have updated the template and I am storing my files in a folder under `/media/references`

Comment: What is `{{ seating_plan.read }}` supposed to be?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was trying to display the pdf using .read that I saw on a tutorial somewhere, is that the wrong way to display it?

Comment: Well, `seating_plan` is an instance of References. It should be clear from your code that it has no field or method called `read`. But also you need to think about what you actually want to output. You don't want to read a PDF in your tempate; you want to output a link to an uploaded file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there a way to link to the reference object directly through an anchor tag? Because when i do this `<a href="{{ seating_plan }}">link </a>` the link just says `referenceobject1`.

Comment: Of course there is, but once again you need to think about what you are linking *to*. Again, `seating_plan` is the entire References object. The thing with the PDF link is the `reference_file` field, which in turn has a `url` method. So: `{{ seating_plan.reference_file.url }}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That makes it much more clearer, but however when I do that the page returns `The current path, media/filename.pdf, didn't match any of these.` 404 error?I pasted a file in that folder with the name yet it still shows. And in my model field I set the `upload_to = 'references/'`why is it still looking in the media folder?

Comment: What is your MEDIA_URL setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and i also added this in my urls `if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`